# CSS Native Snap Points: How?

Tags: css, safari, webkit

I was reading the Safari developer docs and it lists these as a new feature supported in Safari 9 (seems like IE and Firefox have support, too) but I can't find any decent documentation on how to use this...

Has anyone tried this yet?  Got it working? Can you please point to some working code?  Thanks.

Comment: If all you want is examples, [here](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/css-scroll-snap-points) is a page with examples. But I'm afraid that would make this question off topic. So, do you have a specific issue? Do you have a goal in mind? Are you trying to implement this and it isn't working?

Comment: Thanks.  I wanted to implement it for this new project but could not turn up a decent link via google.